# Is it possible to write to file descriptor opened in C from a Lua function?

Tags: c, lua

I have a small C program that calls a Lua function and sends it a file descriptor, is it possible to write to this file descriptor from Lua ?

Comment: @SethCarnegie do I have to export another function ?

Comment: Have you tried Lua's [I/O library](http://lua-users.org/wiki/IoLibraryTutorial)?

Comment: @mux if you really want to do it that way, then yes

Comment: @MichaelMior yes it doesn't work, it prints to the standard output, isn't there any function that I can call from lua with an integer file descriptor ? like write(2), or do I have to export it ?

Comment: I think I found a very ugly way, if I redirect the stdout to the socket fd,  before call the lua function, it may work, but forget it, I will just return the string and write it in C.

Comment: @mux Please answer your own question and mark your answer as correct. Otherwise this question keeps appearing on the "unanswered" list.

Comment: @mux FYI, looked over the source to the Lua I/O lib. It seems there is indeed no way to write to a file descriptor :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think redirecting the standard output to the socket fd, before calling the lua function, may work, but it's easier to just return the string and write it in C.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the C function fdopen().
It takes a file descriptor and gives you back a stream/FILE*.

If you implement a Lua C extension for fdopen() to give you back a LuaStream then you can use the normal Lua io calls on the resulting Lua Stream.

Better than just implementing a one-off function for what you want to do.

see io_open in liolib.c of the Lua 5.2.1 sources for an example of creating a Lua Stream.